# I am deploying my express app on a2 hosting but getting object progressevent error

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, hosting

I am getting object progress event error during deployment of my app. I am also attaching the screenshot of the error. I am using an vps managed hosting.

screenshot

[image: 1]

I have tried different version of Node.js but still getting same error.

Comment: what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get some more information by specifying the passenger.log file in your app setup (the bottom input in the screenshot you've attached which is currently blank). Then try restarting the app so you get error alert in your screenshot and check the log file for details. You can access the log file by browsing to it in the cPanel file manager.

Hopefully that allows you to get a bit more info on the error